# ColdFusion setting cookies on a specific subdomain

Tags: coldfusion, cfcookie

I have a domain www.example.com with two sub domains

```
foo.example.com
bar.example.com
```

I want to set a cookie for all subdomains except foo.example.com , Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Currently I have tried,

```
<cfcookie name="cookieName" value="cookieValue" expires="never" domain=".example.com" path="/">
```

But it sets this cookie on all sub-domains.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you wish for a cookie set on *foo.example.com* to be read by both *foo.example.com* and *example.com* but **not** by *bar.example.com*. I don't think you can do this - at least not using the native application of domain cookies. The domain cookies allow a cookie set in a parent to be read by subsequent children. Since foo and bar are both children of example.com in the heirarchy, they would be able to read a domain wide cookie.